# JavaScript object array not importing correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this array of objects defined as:

```
export const trace: IStackTrace[] = [
  {
    ordered_globals: ["c"],
    stdout: "",
    func_name: "<module>",
    stack_to_render: [],
    globals: {
      c: ["REF", 1]
    },
    heap: {
      "1": ["ARRAY", 1, ["REF", 2]],
      "2": ["ARRAY", 2, null]
    },
    line: 2,
    event: "return"
  },
  {
    ordered_globals: ["c", "d"],
    stdout: "",
    func_name: "<module>",
    stack_to_render: [],
    globals: {
      c: ["REF", 1],
      d: ["REF", 3]
    },
    heap: {
      "1": ["ARRAY", 1, ["REF", 2]],
      "2": ["ARRAY", 2, null],
      "3": ["ARRAY", 1, ["REF", 1]]
    },
    line: 2,
    event: "return"
  }
];
```

import:

```
import { trace } from "./Examples";
```

This code works;

```
const StackTraceView = (props: IProps) => {
   const [stepNumber, setStepNumber] = useState<number>(0);
   const trace = ...
   const currentTrace = trace[stepNumber];
   // ...
}
```

This does not

```
import { trace } from "./Examples";

const StackTraceView = (props: IProps) => {
   const [stepNumber, setStepNumber] = useState<number>(0);
   const currentTrace = trace[stepNumber];
   // ...
}
```

[image: Comparison between "currentTrace" objects]

The objects appear the same to me. But my view disagrees.

When I declare and initialize this variable as above inside my React component, then this variable works as expected and my display shows the trace. However, when I put this object into another file and import, or if I declare this object in the "global" space, deep properties of the object seem to be null and my display breaks.

I have no idea what the difference is between declaring this deep object array inside function scope versus importing it is. I tried to deep object clone and still had the same result.

Any help understanding what is going on is much appreciated.

Edit: Added further context. Real question is what the difference between this variable declaration within a function, or using the variable when it is declared outside function scope.

Comment: can you paste your import statement?

Comment: I don't see you ever exporting `trace`... If you don't export it, how come would it be imported? :)

Comment: Yes, the statement is now in my post. So I export with export const trace... and import like so and it does not work. Otherwise, if I move this variable declaration above my function, it still does not work.

Comment: I have added the export to my post to be more clear. But it is not that I have getting a compile error, or even a runtime error. I am just getting different results in my view if I declare the variable in the function or have it in another scope.

Comment: Can you confirm that `trace` is not be accessed and modified by other code in your project? ie, if you change the `trace` variable to be named `foo`, does that rule out any "rouge libraries" as the cause of unexpected data?

Comment: @DacreDenny I can confirm. Only place I use it.

Comment: Are you able to provide some more context? ie, code in the surrounding source file, project config, or a github repo?

Comment: show us the mangled object you claim is different from the original?

Comment: @Dan I have added a comparison of the objects. There appears to be no difference. It is the strangest thing. This object is accessed once and is only read only where I just assign variables from the properties.

Comment: add "export default trace;" after object definition

Comment: You need to show us how you're "testing" this. Show us the objects (all of it) and not just a picture of a , before and after. Show us the view you're applying this to that shows you why it's not working. Point out what makes the results you're seeing "wrong".

Answer (score 0):

I found out if I import the array of objects as before, then I run:

```
const traceJson: string = JSON.stringify(trace);
// then
const traceObject = JSON.parse(traceJson);
// ...
```

That this works correctly. I still have no idea what is causing this. It must be the format of my object that I am importing. Somehow the function must correct JSON irregularities while outside the function scope, it does not.

If someone sees a problem with my JSON, and/or can tell me what is the difference between these scopes, I would be happy to learn and will mark your answer accepted.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: there is something else going on that you are not considering - you have showed us that the object is the same - some logic in your app is changing your object OR your view logic is not properly using your object.